# Relative difference sets?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-designs

Do you know how to find order of known groups with RDS or without? Or Known groups which have RDS or not? If there is a references to survey all researches?

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of stuff around on this, for instance:

- [Alexander Pott, "A survey on relative difference sets"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=243034);
- [La Jolla Difference Set Repository](https://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets/refs.html).

(The latter link contains an online tool and numerous further references, including links to nine papers qualified as surveys and about 20 more research papers).

Comment: The second link seems to be dead - here is a [snapshot from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170711150650/https://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets/refs.html). Dan Gordon still has some stuff related to difference sets [on a new website](https://www.dmgordon.org/diffset/).